# Ionic http observable workflow with API call to remote back end

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs, ionic3, observable

I'm a little confused on how to create a logical API structure in my Ionic app. I've been googling back and forth on the topic. I've seen many posts about observables, promises and async/await. Josh Morony has written and screencasted a few useful intro tutorials on this. And I'm at the point where I think the `http` class in Ionic/Angular will only ever tell me if anything has changed.

Basically this is my code structure:

```
join() {
    let data = {
        key1: 'value1', ...
    };

    let response = this.myApi.join(data);

    if(response.status === 'VALID') {
        // change root
    } else {
        // display error
    }
}
```

In my API provider

```
join(data) {
    return this.http.post(this.apiEndPoint + 'session/join', JSON.stringify(data), {headers: this.headers})
        .subscribe((data) => {
            return data;
        });
}
```

I'm unable to wait for the request to the API to complete and proceed with the response data.

**So my question:**

How do I create a logical information flow where I verify user input from the app on a remote server, wait for the response and proceed based on that result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should subscribe to your Observable in the component & only return the observable in your service provider:

```
  join() {
        let data = {
            key1: 'value1', ...
        };
        let response:any;
        this.myApi.join(data).subscribe(data => {response = data
     if(response.status === 'VALID') {
            // change root
        } else {
            // display error
        }

    });
}
```

In your API provider

```
join(data) {
    return this.http.post(this.apiEndPoint + 'session/join', JSON.stringify(data), {headers: this.headers});
}
```

Comment: I can't believe I kept overlooking this obvious approach. Thanks a lot for your reply. +1A